# Power steering out after driving through deep puddle

Tags: mazda, power-steering

When I was driving to work today in my Mazda B3000 truck when I went through a rather deep puddle of water. Immediately my battery indicator went on and it was very difficult to steer, as if my power steering went out. A little later I saw a "check gauge go on" for about 30 seconds and then went back off. Any ideas what could have caused this?

Comment: How is it running now?

Comment: I parked it at my work and its been sitting there so I may try to start it up around lunch and report back.

Comment: Is the power steering electric or hydraulic?

Comment: @Hobbes - It should be hydraulic.

Comment: What's with [Mazdas and puddles](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/41015/16806) in the past couple days? Both of these made HNQ.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My first thought is that the belt(s) that drive the accessories (alternator and power steering) slipped due to being wet.  As for the check gauges light that came on later, I don't know.  When it came on, did you catch which gauges where high or low?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not, it was very brief. I'm thinking it's the belt as well since everything else seems to work alright.

Comment: Happens a lot while off-roading, especially older Vee-belt (rather than polyvee) belts.

Comment: Took it into the mechanic and he saw the belt dangling underneath my car as I drove up. Restrung it and everything is good to go. Thanks!